# Encrypt .gpg and .ssh folder in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, encryption, truecrypt

I'll move to another country next week (for a college project). I'll take my laptop with me. I run Ubuntu 16.04. The last days I review many ways to protect my data. One of the most interesting ones (among Truecrypt) is Home encryption. But, I read that causes performance issues. I'm a developer (thing many many many small text files). My specs consists of 2GHz CPU (Intel Pentium 6200) and 2GB RAM. Any drawback in performance are not an option. At all...

After reviewing my files I understood that the most vulnerable folders are `.gpg` and `.ssh`. And this is **CRUCIAL**. These folders are the only that can cause me very bad damage to my project.

I try to find the best option to encrypt these folders. To avoid loosing my credentials. I don't know if there is any other way around. The other option is to manually encrypt/decrypt the folders every time I need them through a Truecrypt Volume.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a SSD disk? What computer model is that?

Comment: @gronostaj LENOVO G560 with HDD. (I don't know if this information is required but I'm a Web Developer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu's "Home encryption" is based on eCryptFS, which also has an option to only create an encrypted `~/Private/` directory instead. Run `ecryptfs-setup-private`, then move your secret files to that directory, and symlink them back (using `ln -vns`).

Comment: can you add external links to that method please? Or be more specific?

Comment: Found the official article quit good: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory